# C++, how to load images and count pixels of certain colours

Tags: c++, image, devil

here's my problem:

I'm looking for a way to import an image into C++ then traverse its pixels, incrementing a counter every time a pixel of a certain colour is found.

I've done some research, but I haven't found anything particularly useful.  [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) looks like a good option, but I'm not sure where to start.

Here's a bit of C++/python pseudo-code hopefully illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
for image in folder:

    A = 0;
    B = 0;

    for pixel in image:

        if (pixel == colourA) {A++}
        if (pixel == colourB) {B++}

    //Output the count of colours for each image
    outputToFile(A, B);
```

Does anyone have some tips on where to start?

Thanks

EDIT
Some extra information: I'm using Windows 7 and all the images are .pngs

EDIT2
I've got everything working, except actually finding out the colour of the current pixel.  Currently I'm using this:

```
int blue = ((uchar *)(img->imageData + pixelX*img->widthStep))[pixelY*img->nChannels + 0];
```

But it doesn't work, and I have no idea how it works.  I haven't been able to find anything about this that I could understand.  Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to find the RGB values of a certain pixel?

Edit3
Done!  For anyone who finds this trying to do a similar thing, most of my remaining questions and a fair bit of code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851604/c-access-violation-using-opencv-to-get-rgb-value-of-pixel).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're trying to compute a (partial) histogram. Your average graphics library should be able to do this for you (imagemagick, at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definiately take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html) because when you begin to need more room to move then OpenCV will let you do many more computer vision tasks. And use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) to do the 'for each image in dir' code.

Note that the [cv::compare](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-compare) function basically does half the work for you already...I'll let you read that and enjoy leveraging the OpenCV API.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on platform and image format. In Windows, BMP images are supported natively (i. e. in the API). ImageMagick is a cross-platform library, pretty universal, takes about any format out there, but it's heavy. Qt has some image processing as well - limited to the most common formats.

Answer (score 0):

SDL has some useful pixel manipulation stuff.

http://www.libsdl.org/

It's very clean as well.